# R replace NA with value from adjacent row

Tags: r, zoo

I have a dataframe "df" with two columns. Column 2 contains both valid strings and missing values filled with "NA".

Input Example:

```
> df

ENSMMUG00000023296 PGBD2 
ENSMMUG00000036181 U6
ENSMMUG00000064799 NA
ENSMMUG00000057389 LYPD8
```

I want to replace the "NA" values with the corresponding value from column 1. To achieve the following output.

Desired Output Example:

```
> df

ENSMMUG00000023296 PGBD2 
ENSMMUG00000036181 U6
ENSMMUG00000064799 ENSMMUG00000064799
ENSMMUG00000057389 LYPD8
```

I attempted to do this using the na.locf tool from the zoo package but I don't understand how to specify that the replacement value should be taken from column 1.

Failed Attempt:

```
> library(zoo)
> na.locf(df)

ENSMMUG00000023296 PGBD2 
ENSMMUG00000036181 U6
ENSMMUG00000064799 U6
ENSMMUG00000057389 LYPD8
```

Comment: Just do `df$col2[is.na(df$col2)] <- df$col1[is.na(df$col2)]`. (assuming that 'df' is a data.frame.  Please do change the names of the columns with your column names)

Answer (score 1):

Another option, assuming you have a data.frame with columns 'column1' and 'column2'

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(~column1, ~column2,
              'ENSMMUG00000023296', 'PGBD2',
              'ENSMMUG00000036181', 'U6',
              'ENSMMUG00000064799', NA,
              'ENSMMUG00000057389', 'LYPD8')
df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   column1            column2
#>   <chr>              <chr>  
#> 1 ENSMMUG00000023296 PGBD2  
#> 2 ENSMMUG00000036181 U6     
#> 3 ENSMMUG00000064799 <NA>   
#> 4 ENSMMUG00000057389 LYPD8

mutate(df, column2 = ifelse(is.na(column2), column1, column2))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   column1            column2           
#>   <chr>              <chr>             
#> 1 ENSMMUG00000023296 PGBD2             
#> 2 ENSMMUG00000036181 U6                
#> 3 ENSMMUG00000064799 ENSMMUG00000064799
#> 4 ENSMMUG00000057389 LYPD8
```

Comment: If you are sure there are no missing values on `df$column1`, you could also do `mutate(df, column2 = coalesce(column2, column1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the below, assuming you have two columns:-

```
df$column2[is.na(df$column2)] <- df$column1[is.na(df$column2)]
```

This does not cover the edge case in which the second column in also `NA`.

Comment: I saw your comment now, yes it is the same.